# input box shading using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can I make a shaded background for an input box, as shown [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/07/27/Enhance-your-input-fields-with-simple-CSS-tricks.aspx)(scroll down a little), using jQuery or CSS?

**EDIT**: I don't want to use an image as background.

Comment: I think he meant this: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/07/27/Enhance-your-input-fields-with-simple-CSS-tricks.aspx But then that's kind of confusing because that's a tutorial on how to do it so I'm not sure what he's asking

Comment: I don't want to use an image. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer shadow

```
input {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Inner Shadow

```
input {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow:inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure this is IE safe is it?  I know FF, Chrome and Safari will probably render these no probs but IE is always the wildcard

Comment: This make a shadow, but I want **shading inside** the input box. Thanks though.

Comment: Done. You can do that by setting the `inset` attribute. You can customize from there. The link didn't work so I can get it exact.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! (I changed the link.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually that would be a background image so you can set a css class for the text box and use that image in the background-image property.

So I don't think you'd use jQuery in this but then I can't get to the link you have posted.

If you need to set it via jQuery then use the .addClass("classname") jquery method on the object.

Comment: I would prefer not using a background image. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Not really no.  Looking at the image, now the link works, you just need an image which is ipx wide and the css with automtically repeat it for you so the overhead is minimal.  You can certainly put a gradient in boxes but it's not IE safe